# I need to know what resistor i need for my expirement?

Tags: voltage, resistors, amperage, watts

Im doing and expirement with electricity. Im using 120v  input. I have my device i created (im not gona go into detail with what i made other than its a wireless electricity generator that im trying to invent). So here is my problem i have a 120v input and my device has an ohm resistance of 0.5. Now heres my issue i need to get up to 6 ohms. This is because of the equation V=IR.
120V = I x 0.5. I would obviously be 240 Amps. I have a breaker of 20A. This means it blows every time i turn my device on. So i need to ge my amps down to 20 but i want to be at as close to 20 as possible. So i need a resistor that will be 5.5 to 6 ohms and can take 2400 watts because 120V x 20A = 2400W. Now im not to sure that they have this so what i could do is get 6 1ohm resistors that each can handle 400 watts. Please help i need to know what resistor(s) i need.

Thank you

K look guys what I am making is a wireless electricity generator. I design needs a primary coil with the primary coil is what has .5 ohm resistance. This coil is wrapped around a steel rod. This will produce an electromagnet. If you know how a transformer works. There is a core with two coils wrapped in there. The primary coil is given its voltage. It creates an electromagnet and the secondary coil induces it. The point of a core on a transformer is too direct the electro magnet to the secondary coil. With my design I do not need A core. This is because the electromagnet will spread around which is my objective. It will lose a lot of this power. This secondary coil is what induces it just like a transformer. The reason why I need as much apps as possible, it's because amps are what you need to make an electromagnet. The more the amps the more the power. And I know electricity can be dangerous but I am experienced and I am doing it with my physics teacher. Thanks again

Comment: Try an electric kettle. BTW an "expirement" (with electricity) could be fatal!

Comment: @Andy aka: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=expirement

Comment: What sort of a generator _consumes_ 2,400 W from the mains?

Comment: It's great that you are trying to learn through experimentation and this site is a great place for advice. However, you might have noticed that you have received negative votes. Your grammar and spelling make you sound like you are 4 years old and it makes it hard to take your question seriously. I suspect you would have received even more advice and answers if your question was worded more like an adult wrote it. I don't mean to be rude or make you feel bad and I encourage you to continue with your learning and experimentation - maybe you will come up with something great

Comment: FYI, coreless transformers are way inefficient, that's why they're not used unless strictly necessary. Also what you're building here is a [wireless transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_power) device, not a generator.

Comment: TLDR : Don't use a resistor for impedance matching; use a transformer.

Answer (score 4):

If the objective is to deliver a controlled amount of AC power to a load, the usual way is using a step-down transformer to reduce the AC voltage presented to the load. This also has the effect of transforming the load impedance seen by the AC mains.

So if you wanted to deliver about 15Arms into a purely resistive 0.5ohms load (112 watts from 120Vrms AC mains), then the mains transformer needs to step down 120Vrms to 7.5Vrms, which is a turns ration of 16:1. This would deliver 112 watts (7.5Vrms x 15Arms at a power factor of zero degrees).

However, since this is for an experiment, I would strongly urge you to use an `Autotransformer` (also known as a `Variac` or `Variable Transformer`) instead of building a fixed 16:1 step-down transformer. This is a big, heavy copper winding with a big, friendly knob that you can use to actually turn down the AC voltage (or even turn up the voltage above mains voltage).

I'm assuming that you have at least a DMM, some wire cutters, and another person standing by in case things go sideways. You know to keep one hand in your pocket, to avoid creating a conductive pathway through your heart, right?

Also, I notice you refer to the mains voltage as 120V instead of 120Vrms even though it is AC rather than DC, which makes me wonder whether you are fully aware of the difference between `impedance` and `resistance`. This is one of the things that makes AC circuits a bit harder to deal with than DC. For purely resistive loads, the current and voltage are in phase, and only real power is delivered. But inductive and capacitive loads have current and voltage out of phase, so it's more complicated to describe -- there is both real power and reactive power, since peak current and peak voltage do not occur at the same time.

Your experimental rig may measure 0.5ohms DC resistance, but since you describe it as a primary coil / electromagnet / antenna, there could be significant inductive reactance -- which affects the power factor and the load impedance. So it could draw a lot more power than you expect. That's why it's useful to have an autotransformer, so you can slowly ramp up the power from 0 and see how much it can take without burning something.

By the way, other "energy transmission" rigs I've seen use higher frequency instead of just using the 60Hz mains frequency; this supports using a more directed transmitting antenna instead of throwing power and EMI around in unwanted directions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use two 1200 watt 120 volt electric heaters connected in parallel, but that would waste a helluva lot of power.

It would be better to redesign your device so that it appears as an 8 ohm or more resistor.  (It is bad practice to load a circuit to its full rated capacity - you should try to stay under 80% of capacity, so 16 Amps on your 20 Amp circuit.)